# "The girl I love hates me" or "The girl who I love hates me"

Tags: relative-clauses

> The girl I love hates me

Is the sentence grammatically correct?

My teacher says it should be

> the girl **who** I love hates me

Comment: Side problem with your teacher's version: "who" should be "whom"

Comment: If your teacher is really that picky it should be 'the girl *whom* I love', but this borders on archaic.

Comment: Your teacher can't be a native speaker of any form of standard English used in the northern hemisphere if he or she thinks there is anything wrong with "the girl I love". I would suspect that this person has not been exposed to any actual English literature or other language-based cultural artifacts: films, songs, ..

Comment: @Kaz: The second form may or may not be "grammatically correct", but at a guess at least 99% of native English speakers would use the first.

Comment: If this is the case, who cares...

Comment: Pro tip: if your friend tells you: "The girl I love hates me", don't respond by correcting their grammar.

Comment: whom is archaic. I have never heard anyone outside of an English class used it.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane Depends where you live. Some of us do still speak English! "archaic" does _not_ mean "my particular culture doesn't tend to use it at present"

Comment: @KeithLoughnane, it is still used often enough in written English. Not always correctly ;)

Comment: I hope your teacher gets shown a transcript of this!

Comment: Everyone who says "whom" is correct -- it's not. "Whom" is for indirect objects. As I understand it, you would use "The girl who I love" or "The girl to whom I have pledged my love." They are not interchangeable grammatically. "The girl who wore a dress" not "The girl whom wore a dress. No?

Comment: @user8356: No.  The reason it is "The girl who wore a dress" is because the girl is the subject of the dependent clause.  Both direct and indirect objects will use *whom*, as well as prepositional objects (such as in your example `to whom I have pledged" -- that is not an indirect object either, it is the object of a preposition.  An indirect object would be "me" in "Show me a picture of the girl you love.").

Comment: @KeithLoughnane I used to think the same thing, that "whom" is archaic; I don't recall ever hearing it used seriously throughout my childhood or high school.  In fact I specifically remember in the 1985 movie "Real Genius" in which the Val Kilmer character used it consistently, and it seemed strange.  That said, I've since then been in different regions and subcultures and found that "whom" is certainly used in some of them, so I no longer think it's archaic.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's a great explanation without too much jargon. You're right, I mixed up use of 'whom' as the object of a preposition with an indirect object. People, go with what Ben wrote. But what about 'the girl whom I love' vs. 'who I love?'

Answer (score 34):

Unfortunately, your teacher is wrong.

A relative pronoun can be dropped when the relative clause has a non-subject gap, that is, a missing element that is not functioning as the subject of the clause. In this case, the missing element is the direct object of the verb "love". Therefore, the relative pronoun can be safely omitted.

> The girl [(who) I love ___ ] hates me
>
> (The '___' indicates the gap)

Now compare:

> *She is the girl [___ hates me]

The sentence above is ungrammatical. That's because the gap is in the subject position. It should be:

> She is the girl who [___ hates me]

Comment: There are cases, however, where it should be retained to provide clarity.

Comment: @Accumulation Yeah, agreed. Sometimes the relative clause might be too long so you'll need the relative pronoun as a marker.

Answer (score 10):

I hope your teacher didn't say that!  The first is perfectly proper but for the second to be grammatical it would have to be "The girl who**m** I love"!

Comment: Modern usage allows who in place of whom (in most cases)

Comment: The "who" is acceptable objective case in modern English.

Comment: @user247327 It could be that only Valley Girls used who instead of whom in 1920, but today it is "who" as an object is acceptable even in formal speaking and writing. That ship sailed decades ago. I like "whom" and use it myself, but it's just a personal choice.

Comment: In modern English, the use of "who" in place of "whom" is widely accepted. The only place you can't use "who" is when it is directly preceded by a preposition: *"to who you're talking?".

Comment: @user178049 "To who you're talking?" isn't grammatical. "To whom are you talking?" is grammatical but pretentiously archaic. "Who are you talking to?" is modern English. And nobody (except possibly a few Americans who haven't given up obsolete expressions) would say "Whom are you talking to?"

Comment: @alephzero Prepositional stranding is informal. "Whom", on the other hand, is highly formal. The awkwardness of "whom you're talking to?" is probably due to the conflicting styles. But it is still grammatical, at least according to some style guides.

Comment: Please [edit] this to add quotes/references to reliable sources who support your claim "the girl who I love" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @user178049 For a question, it would have to be "are you", not "you're/you are".

Comment: @mwfearley Aah.. Yes exactly. I thought it was a relative clause.

Comment: @user178049 I think this may be a regional thing: I've certainly never found "whom" to be considered "formal" in British English.

Comment: @alephzero Why "Americans" specifically?

Comment: You must have a cloth ear if you think that anybody would ever say "the girl whom I love". It is true that some people still use 'whom', but never in this context.

Comment: @alephzero To really drive it home, "To whom you're talking?" isn't that grammatical either, and "To who are you talking?" doesn't really sound that bad to my ears (though obviously I would use something more "normal" like "Who are you talking to?").

Comment: @Chronocidal _Whom_ is **more** formal in some dialects (actually, probably more in some sociolects) than others, but it is marked for formality everywhere, also in BrE. In informal spoken structures, you will almost never hear it. Things like, “Oi, whom do you think you’re talking to?” or “Whom are you talking to?” are highly unlikely everywhere.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you're being formal, then the [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) means the answer would be "It is he" / "it is she", which would make "who are you talking to?" correct, but "I am talking to her/him" means "to who**m** are you talking?"  :P  But, I think the real point here is that what some places would consider to be "normal", others would considered "uneducated", while what other consider "normal" can be considered "formal" elsewhere, while the typical balance of language lies somewhere between the two.  That sound 'bout right, innit?

Comment: @Chronocidal No, in “Who are you talking to?”, _who_ remains the object of the preposition _to_; there is no subject complement in that sentence. I should have been a bit clearer above: _whom_ is marked for formality everywhere as a free alternant with _who_ in non-subjective position. As the object of a preposition, _whom_ is (almost) mandatory _if_ it directly follows the preposition – but this construction is inherently marked as formal, so the marking applies even here.

Answer (score 5):

In the US such an instance of *"who"/"whom"* would be considered redundant or stuffy, and the usual usage would be:

> The *noun* **that** I *verb* opposite-*verb*(s) me.

Or, the implied version:

> The *noun* I *verb* opposite-*verb*(s) me.

---

Note: *"noun who"* vs. *"noun that"*, the rule seems to be that for a proper noun, (one that refers to a specific individual, or emphasizes a person's unique traits), use *who*; and for a noun that emphasizes class or set membership, (*i.e.* the class or set of all beloved young women), use *that*.

So if there were three girls named Mary standing in a row, then to say:

```
The Mary who I love is that girl on the right.
```

...would distinguish the individual Mary #3 as your favorite, who happens to be girl #3 as well.

Comment: There are various pro-con usage articles about *who vs. that* online, but SFAIK those tend to take several pages to say what's summarized above, making it a bit pointless to reference them...